# Exception while trying to run flutter app on android device

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, exception, build

I developed a flutter project and this project works fine with my ios stimulator but does not run on my android phone (physical phone). I get an exception while trying to run the project.

What is the reason for this?

`Exception`:

```
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Cannot parse project property android.enableJetifier='true ' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 968ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gradle.properties check that you have android.enableJetifier=true without a space behind it.
just remove last space from `'true  '`

```
android.enableJetifier='true '
```

put it like this

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```